# identifying the design pattern name used

Tags: c++, design-patterns

I want to check if the examples below (from a test interview) corresponds to the correct design pattern name :

Example 1 : can that piece of code illustrate the "Builder" pattern or it might be the "Strategy" one ?

```
FileStream* files = new FileStream("my_file.zip");
BufferedStream* bufferds = new BufferedStream(files);
ZipStream* zips = new ZipStream(bufferds);
```

Example 2 : is the code below represent the "Strategy" pattern ?

```
struct UnixText {
void write(string str) { cout << str; }
void lf() { cout << "\n"; }
};

struct WindowsText {
void write(string str) { cout << str; }
void crlf() { cout << "\r\n"; }
};

struct Writer {
virtual void write(string str) = 0;
virtual void newline() = 0;
virtual ~Writer() {}
};

struct UnixWriter : Writer {
UnixWriter(UnixText* tx) { _target = tx; }
virtual void write(string str) { _target->write(str); }
virtual void newline() { _target->lf(); }

private:
UnixText* _target;
};

struct WindowsWriter : Writer {
WindowsWriter(WindowsText* tx) { _target = tx; }
virtual void write(string str) { _target->write(str); }
virtual void newline() { _target->crlf(); }

private:
WindowsText* _target;
};

int main()
{
Writer* writer = (g_IsUnix) ? (Writer*) new UnixWriter(new UnixText()) : (Writer*) new WindowsWriter(new WindowsText());

writer->write("Hello");
writer->newline();
writer->write("World");

}
```

Comment: Naked `new` and raw pointers with unclear ownership semantics everywhere. From a 2018 point of view this is *atrocious* C++ code! If this were from a real interview, I’d ask that company some very serious questions about their position on and plans for C++ from *this* century.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first example uses I/O streams and it is a good use of `Decorator` pattern. Here it has a constructor that takes an instance of the same abstract class or interface. That's the recognition key of the `Decorator` pattern

The second one, you are passing some Writing `Strategy` to the `UnixWriter` and `WindowsWriter` which is the context. So it can be considered as `Strategy` pattern. But you can still improve it by having a contract for Writing Strategy. So your concrete writers should only know about that super type rather than having references to concrete implementations. That will make your system more flexible.

Comment: Perfect ! Thank you for your reply.